# DynamoDB in local Docker Setup: Table not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-dynamodb

I've setup a basic Node application with the DynamoDB Mapper SDK in on container & the `amazon/dynamodb-local` image in another container using docker-compose.

After start up I'm creating a table with `"TableName" = "local-challenge"` via the AWS CLI:

```
aws dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json file://local-challenge-table.json --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000 --region ddblocal
```

This works smoothly, as I can list the table afterwards with `aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000 --region ddblocal`

**Problem**: Accessing the Table within the Node App always ends with the `operation on non-existing table` error.

The client & table looks like this:

```
export class DynamodbClient {

    public client: DynamoDB
    public mapper: DataMapper

    constructor() {
        AWS.config.update({ 
            region: 'ddblocal',
            accessKeyId: '890d14de07cdb7e9', // just random placeholders, else local DynamoDB will complain
            secretAccessKey: '5945200b32c9c9a461577672181db560' // just random placeholders, else local DynamoDB will complain 
        })
        this.client = new AWS.DynamoDB({endpoint: new AWS.Endpoint('http://dynamodb:8000')})
        this.mapper = new DataMapper({
            client: this.client,
            tableNamePrefix: `local-`
        })
    }
}

@table('challenge')
export class ChallengeEntity { ... }
```

If I adapt the configuration to my AWS region and deploy everything it works smoothly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have to facepalm myself here ‍♂️

I've should have used my placeholders for the AccessKeyId as well as the SecretAccessKey at the CLI where I created the tables.

Now it is working fine.

Comment: I don't think it's super intuitive - especially because the cli will let you create a table in local dynamo without any credentials set. I spun my wheels on this for a while as well.